# Deriving total (within class + between class) scatter matrix

Tags: discriminant-analysis

I was fiddling with PCA and LDA methods and I am stuck at a point, I have a feeling that it is so simple that I can't see it.

Within-class ($S_W$) and between-class ($S_B$) scatter matrices are defined as:

$$
S_W = \sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i - \mu_i)(x_t^i - \mu_i)^T
$$

$$
S_B = \sum_{i=1}^CN(\mu_i-\mu)(\mu_i-\mu)^T
$$

Total scatter matrix $S_T$ is given as:

$$
S_T = \sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i - \mu)(x_t^i - \mu)^T = S_W + S_B
$$

where C is number of classes and N is number of samples $x$ are samples, $\mu_i$ is ith class mean, $\mu$ is overall mean.

While trying to derive $S_T$ I came up to a point where I had:

$$
(x-\mu_i)(\mu_i-\mu)^T + (\mu_i-\mu)(x-\mu_i)^T
$$

as a term. This needs to be zero, but why?

---

Indeed:

\begin{align}
S_T &= \sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i - \mu)(x_t^i - \mu)^T \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i - \mu_i + \mu_i - \mu)(x_t^i - \mu_i + \mu_i - \mu)^T \\
&= S_W + S_B + \sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N\big[(x_t^i - \mu_i)(\mu_i - \mu)^T + (\mu_i - \mu)(x_t^i - \mu_i)^T\big]
\end{align}

Comment: The answer is that you are summing the deviations of values around their mean and that sum is zero.  But what, precisely, are $x$, $m$, and $m_i$?  How are $m$ and $m_i$ related to $\mu$ and $\mu_i$?  The quality of answers will depend on how accurately we guess but you're forcing us to do an awful lot of guessing!

Comment: @whuber: You are totally right, I revised my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assume

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^Nx_t^{i}=\mu_i$$

Then

$$\sum_{i=1}^C\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i-\mu_i)(\mu_i-\mu)^T=\sum_{i=1}^C\left(\sum_{t=1}^N(x_t^i-\mu_i)\right)(\mu_i-\mu)^T=0$$

and formula holds. You deal with the second term in the similar way.

Comment: (+1) The second term, being the transpose of the first, must also be zero :-).

Comment: @whuber, yes, that too :)

Comment: Hi,i don't get why the assumption holds?Can someone explain that?

Comment: @Mvkt It is not so much an assumption as the definition of $\mu_i$ I suppose. That is to say: $\mu_i$ is the mean of the observations in group $i$. I expect the answer uses 'assume' because the OP doesn't explain the notation, so we have to guess that the group mean is meant by $\mu_i$.