# When do all PLS components together explain only part of the variance of the original data?

Tags: partial-least-squares

According to this question and answer, the sum of variances of all partial least squares (PLS) components is normally less than 100%: [Why do all the PLS components together explain only a part of the variance of the original data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157087)

Can somebody provide (further) evidence for this? When would this occur?

When running PLS in SAS using the SIMPLS method, I find that 100% of the variance is explained when I use all components.

I have confirmed that the weight vectors produced by PLS in my case are not orthogonal. However, according to *The Elements of Statistical Learning* the outputed components themselves are orthogonal:

> partial least squares produces a sequence of derived, orthogonal
>   inputs or directions $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_M$.

Comment: Components are orthogonal (i.e. have correlation zero), that's right. This does not contradict my answer in the linked thread. What *exactly* do you mean, when you say that 100% variance is explained when you use all components? Are you sure you mean the sum of the variances of the projections on the unit weight vectors?

Comment: Please give more detail of your circumstances where you get 100%. How many observations? How many components? etc. Do you have a small example (small enough to give the data) where this happens?

Comment: I have approximately 100 response and 100 predictor variables and approximately 2,000 observations. I am fairly confident that I mean what I say regarding the variances. Is it possible that the variance explained converges to 100% as the number of observations increases? I did some quick testing in R with the plsr function from the pls package and this seems to occur.

Comment: Did you check whether this 100% corresponds to the matrix $X$ or $Y$? Because the explained variance for matrix $X$ has to be 100% but for matrix $Y$ can be less since you try to approximate $Y$ by a linear model.

Comment: We are discussing the X Matrix.